# Declaring DATETIME in Stored proc MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to get System Datetime for a column when a new row is inserted or updated into a table using stored Proc in MS SQL. How can I achieve it?
I have tried below code

```sql
CREATE PROCEDUCE test_Cl_INSERT
@SRC_ID int,
@CREATED_BY datatime
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT into dbo.CL_Batch(SRC_ID, Created_BY)
VALUES(@SRC_ID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
END

EXEC dbo.test_Cl_INSERT
@SRC_ID=44
```

> ERROR : @CREATED_BY parameter missing

Comment: Considering you don't reference `@CREATED_BY` in your Procedure, why do you need it?

Comment: "END" does not terminate the code for your stored procedure so that EXEC statement is also part of your procedure.

Comment: The code i mentioned here is sample one. I have many columns in my table.

Comment: @SMor I will execute the Stored proc and EXEC statement separately!

Comment: *"The code i mentioned here is sample one. I have many columns in my table."* That doesn't change my statement. In the example you give, you don't reference `@CREATED_BY` so there's no point is existing. That is only further cemented when you then don't include it in your `EXEC` statement. If the example you give above isn't representative of the actual code you have, then post something that *is* representative.

Comment: The statements you have now aren't even syntactically valid, there are multiple typos. Please include a [mre]. If all your question boils down to is "how do I allow a default value for a parameter and ignore it if not supplied" (as I suspect), that's as simple as adding `= NULL` to the declaration and using `ISNULL` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_Cl_INSERT
@SRC_ID int 
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT into dbo.CL_Batch(SRC_ID, Created_BY)
VALUES(@SRC_ID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
END
```

EXEC dbo.test_Cl_INSERT
@SRC_ID=44

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure signature is:

```
CREATE PROCEDUCE test_Cl_INSERT
  @SRC_ID int,
  @CREATED_BY datatime
```

You attempt to execute as:

```
EXEC dbo.test_Cl_INSERT @SRC_ID=44
```

Do you see something missing? You should. Your procedure has 2 parameters but you provide only 1 when you attempt to execute it. That is your problem. As already noted, you don't use that paramter within the logic of the procedure so why does it exist at all?

You must execute your procedure like this:

```
EXEC dbo.test_Cl_INSERT @SRC_ID=44, @CREATED_BY = '20201124 12:49';
```

Notice I just assigned a random value to the parameter since it (the parameter) is not used within your procedure code. That solves the question you ask. However, you have more important issues to consider.